# Combining specific rows in a pandas dataframe into a new row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and for one of my columns, I need to combine some of the values however I'm not sure what function to use (merge, sum, concatenate, etc.) I have a dataframe with 5 columns (postal code, borough, neighbourhood, latitude, longitude) and for the borough column, there are 10 unique boroughs however I need it to be 6 boroughs only, therefore I need to combine 4 of the boroughs(East Toronto, Downtown Toronto, West Toronto and Central Toronto)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7pkr.jpg) into one borough and name this borough Old Toronto. How do I do this without losing all the neighbourhoods in the boroughs which I need to combine?

Comment: Instead of posting a picture of code / output, you should try to post the code directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace them like below:

```
l=['East Toronto', 'Downtown Toronto', 'West Toronto', 'Central Toronto']

df['borough']=df['borough'].str.replace('|'.join(l),"Old Toronto")
```